# How to give names to arrays inside RecursiveArrayIterator?

Tags: php

Originally, I manually created nested `foreach` loops:

```
$first_array_counter = 0;
$second_array_counter = 0;
$third_array_counter= 0;
$fourth_array_counter = 0;

foreach ($nested_array_4_layers as $layer1_items) {
    $first_array['first_array_id'] = $first_array_counter;
    foreach ($layer1_items as $layer2_items) {
        $second_array['second_array_id'] = $second_array_counter;
        foreach ($layer2_items as $layer3_items) {
            $third_array['third_array_id'] = $third_array_counter; 
            foreach ($layer3_items as $layer3_items) {
                $fourth_array['fourth_array_id'] = $fourth_array_counter;
                $fourth_array_counter++;
            }
            $third_array_counter++;
        }
        $second_array_counter++
    }
    $first_array_counter++;
}
```

But now I'm trying to change the code to be dynamic and with varying nesting levels. For example with 3 nesting levels and different names:

```
foreach ($nested_array_3_layers as $layer1_items) {
    $other_first_array['first_array_id'] = $first_array_counter;
    foreach ($layer1_items as $layer2_items) {
        $other_second_array['second_array_id'] = $second_array_counter;
        foreach ($layer2_items as $layer3_items) {
            $other_third_array['third_array_id'] = $third_array_counter;                 
            $third_array_counter++;
        }
        $second_array_counter++
    }
    $first_array_counter++;
}
```

For that I changed the code to use `RecursiveIteratorIterator` with `RecursiveArrayIterator`:

```
$iter = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($nested_array_x_layers), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

foreach ($iter as $k => $v) {
    if (!is_array($v)) {       
    }
}
```

But I still want to be able to control which names the arrays have because I need to later use them.

Would that be done using maybe a switch-case and given options for the array names?

But then, how can I control which nesting level belongs to which name?

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended to use many loops at the same time, by defining keys, combining the arrays first will provide ease of use later.

Table 1

```
$array_1_data = Array (
[0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [name] => IT [slug] => it )
[1] => Array ( [id] => 2 [name] => Accounting [slug] => accounting )
)
```

Table 2

```
$array_2_data = Array (
[0] => Array ( [cid] => 3 [jid] => 24061 )
[1] => Array ( [cid] => 1 [jid] => 24062 )
)
```

Joining via key

```
$result = array_uintersect_uassoc($array_1_data, $array_2_data, function($a, $b){
return strcasecmp($a['id'], $b['cid']);
}, function($a, $b){
return (int) [$a, $b] == ['id', 'cid'];
});
```

conclusion

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
(
[id] => 1
[name] => IT
[slug] => it
)
)
```